# Receiving memory leak

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone Development.
I am displaying lots of images on view.also i put button named LOAD MORE for more images.I am also downloading images on LOAD MORE event.
Here is my code:`

```
-(void)btnLoadMorePressed
{
     [appdelegate showLoader:MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate];

    RequestResponseManager *requestManager=[RequestResponseManager sharedInstance];
    [requestManager setRequestPropery:self ExtraInfo:nil];

    Album *album=[appdelegate.CurrentUser.albumListarray objectAtIndex:indexNum-1];

    NSArray *obj_keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"UserId",@"AlbumId",@"SessionId",@"PageNo",@"ModMethod", nil];
    NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:appdelegate.CurrentUser.userId,album.AlbumId,appdelegate.sessionId,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentPage],@"getPhotoListByAlbumId",nil];
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:obj_keys];
    NSString *jsonString = [jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];
    NSString *requestString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@",jsonString]; 

    currentRequest=JGetAlbumPhotoList;
    [requestManager sendPostHttpRequest:GET_USER_ALBUM_PHOTO_URL RequestType:JGetAlbumPhotoList PostContent:requestString];
}
```

but when i am trying to fetch more images,it gives me memory warning and then suddenly crashing.please help me.thanking you...

Comment: you need to spell out what happens in more detail. What error messages and what stack traces and logging do you have?

Comment: here is my code for image download : 

-(void)StartImageDownload
{
    ImageDownload = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<[appdelegate.CurrentUser.albumImageArray count];i++)
    {
        AlbumPhoto *aPhoto=[appdelegate.CurrentUser.albumImageArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if(!aPhoto.Image)
            [self startIconDownload:aPhoto.ImageName forIndexPath:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
        else {
            ImageDownload++;
        }
    }
}

Comment: -(void)startIconDownload:(NSString*)user forIndexPath:(NSNumber*)index
{
    if([user length] == 0)
        return;
    IconDownloader *iconDownloader = [imageDownloadsInProgress objectForKey:index];
    if (iconDownloader == nil) 
    {
        iconDownloader = [[IconDownloader alloc] init];
        iconDownloader.imageKey=index;
        iconDownloader.imgURL=user;
        iconDownloader.appRecord = self;
        [imageDownloadsInProgress setObject:iconDownloader forKey:index];
        [iconDownloader startDownload];
        [iconDownloader release];   
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

release all objects that you had created and set all objects to null, in dealloc method.

for Ex:

```
- (void)dealloc {

     [super dealloc];

    [image1 release];
    image1=nil;

}
```

Comment: try to write `[image1 release];` this line after adding image1 to view. for ex: `...[self.view addsubview:image1]`and on next line write '[image1 release]'

Comment: Try doing what krunal said in the method didReceiveMemoryWarning. This method gets calles when you receive a memory warning and in this method you should release all content you don't need any more.

Comment: At the very least, perform a print at this point to see if you are receiving a low memory warning within the didReceiveMemoryWarning method.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not just loading too much into memory?  How big are these images?  It sounds less like a leak and more like loading too much.

Comment: How many total images would you say you have loaded when you see the memory error coming up?  From a size perspective have you thought about sizing them down as they come in so that their memory footprint within your app becomes much smaller?  I have had to do this where the images being loaded were very large, but I only needed them for thumbnail, by resizing them as they come in, downto the true size you really need, you save quite a bit of memory and gain in overall perceptible speed.

Comment: see when view will load,default 15 images will be there.and then user want to load more images he/she can.every click on LOAD MORE 15 images will be loaded.and yes i am resizing images.by using this line:NSData  *DataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"],0.15);